# Keeping our front-end Typescript types aligned with our back-end source code types

Tags: java, typescript

We work with Java in the backend, and Typscript in the front, in two separate repos.

Lately, when communicating between the server and client I stopped sending separate preoperties (like userName, and age) to the client, but instead send "RestObjects" (such as UIRestUser) which are a bit more comprehensive and are based on classes in our Java. This Java "RestClasses" are serialized to JSON and parsed to an object by our JS/TS code. My only concern is gaps between our Typescript and Java code. What we currently do is - currently we write parallel  interfaces/types in typescript.

I'd like for the source type to be written only once. What I thought of doing is: On each Java commit - generate a json object (either representing the types `{userName:string, age:number}, or representing an actual object {userName:"Doron", age:32} from which Typescript can infer the types. This could be done with a commit hook or something of the sort.

It is common for typescript users to work with a different language on the server - What practices and solutions could be used to keep types aligned.
Regarding the implementation - any advice or recommended tools/libraries?

Comment: Off site resource requests are explicitly off-topic, but **I *like*** [FlatBuffers](http://google.github.io/flatbuffers/).

Comment: Yep, I think it may fit better over on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider using something like [Conjure](https://palantir.github.io/conjure/#/). It requires you to define your objects in Yaml and then it generates the Java/Typescript code for you. If you use Gradle to build you backend, there's a [gradle-conjure](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-conjure) plugin to make it easy to incorporate the code generation as part of your builds.

If you find that it doesn't quite fit the bill for whatever reason, it might still be a good example of prior art.

Disclaimer: I work at Palantir. We also had trouble keeping backend/frontend object types in sync -- Conjure is an attempt to solve this.